# Wait-Process for children, with timeout

Tags: powershell

My powershell script needs to wait for a process to finish. This process spawns some child processes.

So if I use

```
Start-Process myexe.exe -Wait
```

This works just fine.

However, I need my script to handle cases where this process doesn't finish. E.g. after 1 hour.

So my attempt is this:

```
$process = Start-Process myexe.exe -PassThru
try {
    "Waiting"
    $process | Wait-Process -Timeout 3600 -ErrorAction Stop
    "Done waiting"
}
catch {
    "Stopping process"
    Stop-Process $process -Force
}
```

The problem then is that `Wait-Process` immidiately finishes, because the process `$process` is idle (done?) but it's child processes are not.

So how can I make `Wait-Process` wait for child processes like the `-Wait` flag in `Start-Process`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `get-process` with the process name stored in `$Process` this will catch all instances of this process and allows you to pass all the children through to `Wait-Process`, please see your script updated below

```
$process = Start-Process myexe.exe -PassThru
try {
    "Waiting"
    Get-Process $Process.ProcessName | Wait-Process -Timeout 3600 -ErrorAction Stop
    "Done waiting"
}
catch {
    "Stopping process"
    Get-Process $Process.ProcessName | Stop-Process -Force
}
```

**Edit:** Updated the Stop-Process to use get-process to also capture all children processes.

Comment: For whatever reason, `Wait-Process` just immediately finishes even though descendants of the process is still running. And as I mentioned, `Start-Process myexe.exe -Wait` actually waits for descended (child) processes...

Comment: @birgersp - Can you please confirm if you have tested the script provided above, as this seems to work as you want in testing (admittedly I am using notepad as my test application). Instead of referencing $Process directly, it pulls all processes with the same process name.

Comment: I tested the script you have provided, but it did not work. `Wait-Process` just finishes immidiately.

Comment: @birgersp - What is the application you are using?, does this spawn processes from another application?

Comment: The application is made in-house by other software developers. It's a .NET application that creates other processes.

Comment: @birgersp If you do `$Process | Select *` does it have a handlecount?, also if you do `get-process myexe.exe | Select HasExited,HandleCount` are all the processes "HasExited" status been returned as true? and do all those that specify false have a handle count?

Comment: HandleCount is 18. HasExited is False. How do I check if all that specify false have a handle count?